# Is it possible to specify value of property as property in ant?

Tags: ant, properties, echo

I have a property file which is generated by my ant script itself during execution. And I want to access the value of properties from this generated property file.

For e.g.,

Generated Property File:

```
first.prop=abcd
second.prop=pqrs
```

and in script, I am trying to access it like this,

I am having a property name (that I want to access and is in generated property file) from some other property. That property is `name.prop`.
so,

```
<echo message="${name.prop}"/>
<echo message="${${name.prop}}"/>
```

gives

```
first.prop
${${name.prop}}
```

as output respectively.
What can be the solution over this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from the [doc](https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html):

> Nesting of Braces
>
> In its default configuration Ant will not try to balance braces in
>   property expansions, it will only consume the text up to the first
>   closing brace when creating a property name. I.e. when expanding
>   something like ${a${b}} it will be translated into two parts:
>
> - the expansion of property a${b - likely nothing useful.
> - the literal text } resulting from the second closing brace
>
> This means you can't use easily expand properties whose names are
>   given by properties, but there are some workarounds for older versions
>   of Ant. With Ant 1.8.0 and the the [props Antlib](https://ant.apache.org/antlibs/props/) you can configure Ant
>   to use the NestedPropertyExpander defined there if you need such a
>   feature.

So it is not available easily. Workarounds (using `<script />` or `<macrodef />` can be found [here in the official ant faq](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property).

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried this, to get similar values<br/>
prop.properties contains:

a=val1
b=val2
c=val3
batch.props=a,b,c

<for list="${batch.props}" param="prop">
  <sequential>
    <echo>@{prop} is ${batch.@{prop}}</echo>
  </sequential>
</for>

Got Ans as below:
a is val1
b is val2
c is val3

Enjoy!
```