# how to use property ant?

Tags: ant

I would ask about property ant.After some action I got property

```
<property name="prop" value="test"/>
```

in file **build.properties** .I have the property test

```
test=example
```

I want to get value from build.properties
but when I use

```
<echo>${${prop}}</echo>
```

I got error
Could somebody help me?How I can solve this problem?It's possible in general such way use property?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify value of property as property in ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119611/is-it-possible-to-specify-value-of-property-as-property-in-ant)

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming you have a build.properties file containing:

```
test=example
```

The build file might look like this:

```
<project basedir="." default="default">
 <property file="build.properties"/>
 <property name="prop" value="test"/>

 <target name="default">
  <echo>${test}</echo>
  <echo>${prop}</echo>
 </target>
</project>
```

Comment: nesting does not work that easily. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119611/is-it-possible-to-specify-value-of-property-as-property-in-ant/10123407#10123407

Comment: Yeah. Right.. Seems that I misinterpreted the question a bit.