# ant > map property names into a new set of properties

Tags: ant

I'd like to "map" a bunch of ant properties, based on a prefix (sounds simple enough).

I have a solution, but it's not elegant (having to write out to a properties file, then read it back in!)

**Question:** Is there a quicker/more generic/simpler/out-of-the-box/straight-forward way of doing the below "load-propertyset" within ANT? (... than the example I've provided below)

(Roughly analogous to the [Groovy > ConfigSlurper > Special Environment Configuration](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper#ConfigSlurper-SpecialenvironmentsConfiguration) behaviour.)

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Config">

    <!-- Section 1. (These will be loaded from a property file...) -->
    <property name="a.yyy" value="foo" />
    <property name="a.zzz" value="cat" />
    <property name="b.xxx" value="bar" />
    <property name="b.zzz" value="dog" />

    <macrodef name="load-propertyset">
        <attribute name="prefix" />
        <attribute name="outfile" default="123" />
        <attribute name="propset" default="123" />
        <sequential>
            <propertyset id="@{propset}">
                <propertyref prefix="@{prefix}" />
                <globmapper from="@{prefix}.*" to="*" />
            </propertyset>
            <echo level="debug">Created propertyset - '@{propset}' from prefix='@{prefix}'</echo>
            <tempfile property="@{outfile}" suffix=".properties" deleteonexit="true" />
            <echo level="debug">Writing propset to temp file - '${@{outfile}}'</echo>
            <echoproperties destfile="${@{outfile}}">
                    <propertyset refid="@{propset}"/>
            </echoproperties>
            <echo level="debug">Reading props from temp file - '${@{outfile}}'</echo>
            <property file="${@{outfile}}" />
            <delete file="${@{outfile}}" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <load-propertyset prefix="a" />
    <load-propertyset prefix="b" />

    <echo>>>> Using variables xxx=${xxx} yyy=${yyy} zzz=${zzz}</echo>

</project>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, for instance:

- Can I reference properties within a propertyset? (e.g. ${myprops.yyy} ?)
- I'd like to **avoid** something like ${${filter}.hostname}.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify value of property as property in ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119611/is-it-possible-to-specify-value-of-property-as-property-in-ant)

Comment: @Mark O'Connor, I had a look, if it's just referring to property expansion, then No, that's not what I'm going for. See above re: "I'd like to AVOID something like ${${filter}.hostname}." Please correct me if I've missed something.

Comment: @Mark O'Connor, Or alternatively, if you could provide an example using property expansion (with a 'for' loop I imagine???), I'd be happy to close off the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third-party [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) has an [`<antcallback>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/antcallback_task.html) that takes the [`<antcall>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) and adds the ability to return properties to the caller:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Config" default="run">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />

    <!-- Section 1. (These will be loaded from a property file...) -->
    <property name="a.yyy" value="foo" />
    <property name="a.zzz" value="cat" />
    <property name="b.xxx" value="bar" />
    <property name="b.zzz" value="dog" />

    <macrodef name="load-propertyset">
        <attribute name="prefix" />
        <attribute name="return" />
        <sequential>
            <antcallback target="-empty-target" return="@{return}">
                <propertyset>
                    <propertyref prefix="@{prefix}" />
                    <globmapper from="@{prefix}.*" to="*" />
                </propertyset>
            </antcallback>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="-empty-target"/>

    <target name="run">
        <property name="properties-to-return" value="xxx,yyy,zzz"/>
        <load-propertyset prefix="a" return="${properties-to-return}"/>
        <load-propertyset prefix="b" return="${properties-to-return}"/>

        <echo>>>> Using variables xxx=${xxx} yyy=${yyy} zzz=${zzz}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

The `properties-to-return` concept is a bit of a maintenance burden. Luckily, `<antcallback>` doesn't fail when asked to return a property that wasn't set. Only the `properties-to-return` property needs to be modified when you want a new mapped property.